# Message ID after imap_mail_move

Tags: php, imap

I want to flag a message as unseen after moving it to a new folder with PHP's IMAP functions, s.th. like:

```
$uioTmp = imap_uid($mailbox, $msgNumber);
imap_mail_move($mailbox, $msgNumber, "INBOX.undetected");
imap_clearflag_full($mailbox, $uidTmp, "\\Seen", ST_UID);
```

Because PHP's `imap_mail_move` does not really move the message (instead copies the message and than delete the old one), the new message will get a new message id I think.

Is there a way to get the message id or the correct UIO of the copied message?

Comment: Why don't you flag it as unseen before you move it? The old message will be marked as deleted anyway, so this should not cause any burden. Otherwise you can mark the old message as seen anyway after you've created the copy. Not most straight forward but should work.

Comment: Thank you thousand times! I thought I tried this before without success, but now I tried it again and it worked (no idea what I did wrong before)! Thank you again, problem solved now.

Comment: Just to help opthers, my code now looks like that:
`imap_clearflag_full($mailbox, imap_uid($mailbox, $msgNumber), "\\Seen", ST_UID);
imap_mail_move($mailbox, $msgNumber, "INBOX.undetected");`

Comment: Below your question, you may add your solution as an answer. That is the proper way to do it around here, and will help others to find it. =)

Comment: @J.Steen, you're right, thanks. I tried that - but I'm new so I can answer my own question first in 7 hours. That's why I used the comment function. I will do a real answer tomorrow.

Comment: @trickreich As an older user, one forgets about these limitations to new users. Sorry, and good luck. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to first flag it as unseen and then move it to the folder:

```
imap_clearflag_full($mailbox, imap_uid($mailbox, $msgNumber), "\\Seen", ST_UID);
imap_mail_move($mailbox, $msgNumber, "INBOX.undetected");
```